# UV mapping a Logo on Specific face of object

Tags: materials, uv

I have a rectangle, and added an image texture on the material. I marked the seams and projected from view on the specific face I wanted the blender logo to be shown. Now my first question is when I add the Blender logo to the face, it's applying to the entire object which seems stretched. Why does blender apply it to all the object and not the specific face which is chosen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of the material has nothing to do with the UV layout. You have 3 material slots, 2 of which are empty and apparently not assigned to anything. 
Go into edit mode select everything, assign a material to the 1. slot and press assign. 
Then select only the face the logo is supposed to be on, select the 2. slot and press assign. 
That will fix it in your case, but best practice is to keep it in one material, use a 2. UVLayout just for the logo and mix it in with your main texture (or color).

Comment: Ok Frederick thanks for the information, point taken and understood. And Now Ill be posting regarding some further material explanation.